# Serving favicon.icon from a RiceBox using FileServer

Tags: http, go

I have been struggling with this for a bit. How do I return, from RiceBox, favicon.ico from a static directory?

Here's the code I have, including relevant parts:

```
mux := mux.NewServeMux()
StaticBox := rice.MustFindBox("static")
StaticFileServer := http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(StaticBox.HTTPBox()))
mux.Handle("/static/", StaticFileServer)
mux.HandleFunc("/", Home)
```

Note: favicon.ico lives inside the static directory among other assets like, js/, css/, etc.

404 when fetching it:

```
$ wget http://localhost:9000/favicon.ico
--2018-03-02 09:40:08--  http://localhost:9000/favicon.ico
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:9000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-03-02 09:40:08 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Does wget ```http://localhost:9000/static/favicon.ico``` returns 404?

Comment: @lhdv, that does work. I guess I am not understanding the `StripPrefix("/static/", ...) method`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrangled this solution, hope it helps someone:

```
func FavIcon(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   StaticBox := rice.MustFindBox("static")
   faviconContent, _ := StaticBox.HTTPBox().Open(r.URL.Path)
   http.ServeContent(w, r, r.URL.Path, time.Now(), faviconContent) 
}

$ wget http://127.0.0.1:9000/favicon.ico
--2018-03-02 23:44:01--  http://127.0.0.1:9000/favicon.ico
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1150 (1.1K) [image/x-icon]
Saving to: ‘favicon.ico’
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/farhany/0fbf84e265ec3e6f3502675e83008149